# Differences in null declaration

Tags: c#

Take the following:

`obj myVar;`

and

`obj myVar = null;`

Is there an actual difference between these two - and are they both caught by `(myVar == null)`?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. You're confusing objects and references. `obj` is a reference, not an object. And that check *does* identify the situation where `obj.anything` would complain "object **reference** not set to an instance of an object". Please clarify.

Comment: AFAIK there is no global error object (accessible to normal code) like in old VB versions.

Comment: if your obj is `null` and you call a function or property of it that's the error you'll get... not sure if I undertood your question

Comment: @JefferyKhan: I think OP is looking for a global error object like in old VB versions.

Comment: Please show your actual code that yields this error.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Why do you think so? He didn't mention this with a single word.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: As an old VB programmer myself, I inferred this possibility. I can think of no other sensible interpretation of what was posted. OP will confirm whether my suspicion is correct  or not.

Comment: Not sure why my question has been down-voted. I was curious, I tried to search for the answer and couldn't find one - I thought SO could give me a good answer, and that I could learn something in the process. Am I supposed to know everything before asking a question? Seriously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer is in your question.  `obj != null` means "the object exists".

However, this is only true **almost all** the time.  A custom override of the `==` and `!=` operator can change this functionality, so to be absolutely sure you can use `!Object.ReferenceEquals(obj,null)` to ensure that the object does exist, in **all** cases.

The error you are getting is a [`System.NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx), and will always be averted by this check.

Comment: +1 for that extra info, even including something the majority of programmers will probably never have any good reason to use. :)

Answer (score 3):

The short, but sweet, answer is: the check `(object != null)` always prevents `object not set to an instance`

Answer (score 1):

### Worth mentioning

If you are reading objects from a database like in the snippet of code below:

```
private object GetItem(DataSet dataSet1, string tableName, int row, int col) {
  object obj = null;
  try {
    obj = dataSet1.Tables[tableName].Rows[row][col];
  } catch (Exception err) {
    Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
  }
  return obj;
}
```

The returned value could be `null` (if an exception were caught) or `DBNull.Value` if `dataSet1.Tables[tableName].Rows[row][col]` was not set in the database.

If, however, you neglect to initialize **object** `obj` as in the example below:

```
private object Test2(DataSet dataSet1) {
  object obj;
  try {
    obj = dataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
  } catch (Exception err) {
    Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
  }
  return obj;
}
```

The code will **not compile** under Visual Studio.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

That is the same thing. If an object is not set to an instance of an object, it will have not have a reference to anything, and will in other words, be `null`.